# How to pass absolute(full) path of a file to ProcessBuilder class

Tags: java

I'm trying to run process builder to execute a file which is inside my **bin/resources/** folder of my java project. For that, I don't want to hard code the complete path, so I'm trying to pass absolute path (full path I mean) using class loader and pass this value as a list argument to ProcessBuilder class. How ever I'm not able to succeed in doing so.

Below code samples (both Case 1 and 2) run fine but nothing happening in the end. I mean the file is not getting called.

Case 1:

```
String rCmd = "Rscript.exe";
String rScriptName = "resources/MyScript.R";
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(rCmd);
list.add(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toURI().toString());
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
pb.start();
```

Case 2:

```
String rCmd = "Rscript.exe";
String rScriptName = "resources/MyScript.R";
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(rCmd);
list.add(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toString());
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
pb.start();
```

Below piece of code throwing exception:
Case 3:

```
String rCmd = "Rscript.exe";
String rScriptName = "resources/MyScript.R";
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(rCmd);
list.add(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toURI());
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
pb.start();
```

Case 4:

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toURI());
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(rCmd);
list.add(file);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
pb.start();
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:361)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1005)
```

Below code gives me expected output but don't want to hard code the path this way, as I need to run this code in linux box later.

```
String rCmd = "Rscript.exe";
String rScriptName = "D:/MyScript.R";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(rCmd, rScriptName);
pb.start();
```

Expecting your much needed help on this!

Comment: Did you try with creating a File Object from the resource?

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana Yes, but that too throwing me the same ArrayStoreException

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana I have updated them as Case 3 and 4

Comment: I put an answer But not sure will it be execute .exe file in Linux environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String rCmd = "Rscript.exe";
        String rScriptName = "filename Without Resource";
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(rCmd);
        list.add([Class name].class.getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toURI().getPath());
```

Was working.

Process builder Expect String Argument So try to parse the list and it will give the below exception unless they are strings.

Try
    this.class.getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toURI().getPath()

It will add the absolute path of the file and it will execute.

[Class ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: Your answer almost worked but with 2 changes. 1) filename Without Resource is throwing NullPointerException, So I provided the file name as "resources/MyScript.R" so that it's looking for it under bin folder. 2) this.class.getClassLoader().getResource(rScriptName).toURI().getPath() is giving me an additional / in the beginning of the path, So I have done a absPath.substring(1) which will eliminate the / in the starting of the path and viola, It all working fine now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: BTW, any clue on why the / is added to the path at the beginning? Also you can up vote my comment if you feel I have provided additional information on top of your answer. :)

Comment: is it like /home/{USER} That is because you are using a Linux OS I think.

Comment: no no, right now I'm still testing this on my windows machine only. Path is taken as /D:/MyScript.R